# Print SageMaker instance type

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

Is there a function I can use to get the instance type of my SageMaker instance.

I basically want to do something like this

```
region = boto3.Session().region_name
```

but for the instance type.

I know I can find it manually, but I want to automate it so that my script can work on any instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DescribeNotebookInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeNotebookInstance.html) API to get the instance size.

```
sm_client = boto3.client("sagemaker")
sm.describe_notebook_instance(
    NotebookInstanceName=<nb-name>
)['InstanceType']
```

Comment: That works, but then the questions is: is there a way to get the name of the notebook instance as well?

Comment: boto3 might not be of help there. You can list all instances, but you'll still have to identify which one you're using. The notebooks have a metadata json here - `/opt/ml/metadata/resource-metadata.json`, that has the notebook name and arn. You could parse that in your notebook code.